# Displaying text in a table view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out why this code will not add any text to the cells in the table. I checked and the array is being filled with text when the button is pressed but nothing shows up in the cell.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var names: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("Mbusi", forKey: "name")
        var name = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")! as String
        println(name)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(names, forKey: "Users")
        var users = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Users")! as [String]


    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func addNameToList(sender: AnyObject) {

        var index = 0
        var namesText = nameTextField.text

        names.append(namesText)
        println(names)


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell  = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

            cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]

            return cell

        }


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you setting your table view's datasource to your view controller?  Also, you need to call `reloadData` on the table view in `addNameToList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

You need to move

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

outside `addNameToList` into your `ViewController`.

And second, you need to call `tableView.reloadData()` after you add items to your `names` array.